# http://timepicker.co/ keyboard navigation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using timepicker in my website, from [here](http://timepicker.co/), but navigation via keyboard is not working.

I want Navigation functionality from keyboard (up and down key) like mouse navigation.

The website demo states:

1. Open website using URL `http://timepicker.co/`,
2. and go to section "Configuration".
3. Now set value 15 in "Interval" text input box.
4. Now verify navigation or scrolling using mouse and keyboard (up/down key).

After doing this, navigation by mouse is working well but not keyboard.

I'd like keyboard navigation to work as well.

My code is the following:

```
$('#start_time').timepicker({
  interval: 15,
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
  scrollbar: true,
  dropDown: true
});
```

Comment: Just push the "Explode" button ...

Comment: "Explode" button ??

Comment: I've no clue what it is, but you can just push it. I've no clue of the "_selected value_" or "_end value_" or "_that part_", or your code either ... "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question__ itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: Hi Teemu, Please go through by updated question, May be now you can understood What am I asking